# debugging the asp.net core web API

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I wrote this API in .net. I am trying to call this method through Fiddler and getting the below error message:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /api/allItProjectsLists/Index</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Not sure what am I doing wrong. Is there any way, I can put a breakpoint inside method Index and find out what is wrong. Below is my API code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ProjectDetails.Models;
using ProjectDetails.Data;
using ProjectDetails.Interfaces;
namespace ProjectDetails.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AllItProjectsListsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly KPIContext _context;
        private readonly IProject objProject;

        public AllItProjectsListsController(IProject _objProject)
        {
            objProject = _objProject;

        }


        [HttpGet("/Index")]
        public IEnumerable<AllItProjectsList> Index()
        {
            return objProject.GetAllProjectDetails();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/AllItProjectsLists/Create")]
        public int Create([FromBody] AllItProjectsList project)
        {
            return objProject.AddProject(project);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/AllItProjectsLists/Details/{id}")]
        public AllItProjectsList Details(int id)
        {
            return objProject.GetProjectData(id);
        }

        [HttpPut]
        [Route("api/AllItProjectsLists/Edit")]
        public int Edit([FromBody]AllItProjectsList project)
        {
            return objProject.UpdateProject(project);
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        [Route("api/AllItProjectsLists/Delete/{id}")]
        public int Delete(int id)
        {
            return objProject.DeleteProject(id);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/AllItProjectsLists/GetAppDevList")]
         public IEnumerable<AppDev> GetAppDev()
         {
                  return objProject.GetAppDevs();
         }
```

any help with the above debugging will be highly appreciated. In Fiddler, I typed the following URL:

https://localhost:44313/api/AllItProjectsLists/Index

Below is the image from Fiddler:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `[HttpGet("/Index")]` to  `[HttpGet("Index")]` on your action for attribute routing.

`[HttpGet("/Index")]` will be executed for a URL as `https://localhost:44313/Index`

`[HttpGet("Index")]` will be executed for a URL as `https://localhost:44313/api/AllItProjectsLists/Index`

Refer to [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0#combining-routes)